# What is the difference between "rabbana lakalhamd" and "rabbana valakalahamd"?

Tags: salat

I heard that that in namaz saying `rabbana lakalhamd` and `rabbana valakalahamd` both are **elgible**.

I want to know what the difference is between `rabbana lakalhamd` and `valakalahamd`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "*wa*" (Arabic: و) means "and", so the difference between:

- *Rabanna wa lakalḥamd* (Arabic: ربنا ولك الحمد)
- *Rabanna lakalḥamd* (Arabic: ربنا لك الحمد)

is the "and" in between.

There are several different forms of praising Allah ﷻ as one rises from *rukū'* that were documented in authentic hadiths, and it is permissible to use either or all of them:

1. *Rabanna wa lakalḥamd* (Arabic: ربنا ولك الحمد)

   > حَدَّثَنَا يَحْيَى بْنُ يَحْيَى، وَقُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، وَأَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ وَعَمْرٌو النَّاقِدُ وَزُهَيْرُ بْنُ حَرْبٍ وَأَبُو كُرَيْبٍ جَمِيعًا عَنْ سُفْيَانَ، - قَالَ أَبُو بَكْرٍ حَدَّثَنَا سُفْيَانُ بْنُ عُيَيْنَةَ، - عَنِ الزُّهْرِيِّ، قَالَ سَمِعْتُ أَنَسَ بْنَ مَالِكٍ، يَقُولُ سَقَطَ النَّبِيُّ صلى الله عليه وسلم عَنْ فَرَسٍ فَجُحِشَ شِقُّهُ الأَيْمَنُ فَدَخَلْنَا عَلَيْهِ نَعُودُهُ فَحَضَرَتِ الصَّلاَةُ فَصَلَّى بِنَا قَاعِدًا فَصَلَّيْنَا وَرَاءَهُ قُعُودًا فَلَمَّا قَضَى الصَّلاَةَ قَالَ ‏ "‏ إِنَّمَا جُعِلَ الإِمَامُ لِيُؤْتَمَّ بِهِ فَإِذَا كَبَّرَ فَكَبِّرُوا وَإِذَا سَجَدَ فَاسْجُدُوا وَإِذَا رَفَعَ فَارْفَعُوا وَإِذَا قَالَ سَمِعَ اللَّهُ لِمَنْ حَمِدَهُ.‏ فَقُولُوا رَبَّنَا وَلَكَ الْحَمْدُ.‏ وَإِذَا صَلَّى قَاعِدًا فَصَلُّوا قُعُودًا أَجْمَعُونَ ‏"‏.‏
   >
   > Anas ibn Malik reported: The Apostle of Allah (ﷺ) fell down from a horse and his right side was grazed. We went to him to inquire after his health when the time of prayer came. He led us in prayer in a sitting posture and we said prayer behind him sitting, and when he finished the prayer hesaid: The Imam is appointed only to be followed; so when he recites takbir, you should also recite that; when he prostrates, you should also prostrate; when he rises up, you should also rise up, and when he said" God listens to him who praises Him," you should say:" Our Lord, to Thee be the praise," and when he prays sitting, all of you should pray sitting.
   >
   > <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 4, Hadith 83](https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/83)</sub>
2. *Allahumma rabanna lakalḥamd* (Arabic: اللهم ربنا لك الحمد)

   > حَدَّثَنَا قُتَيْبَةُ بْنُ سَعِيدٍ، حَدَّثَنَا الْمُغِيرَةُ، - يَعْنِي الْحِزَامِيَّ - عَنْ أَبِي الزِّنَادِ، عَنِ الأَعْرَجِ، عَنْ أَبِي هُرَيْرَةَ، أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏ "‏ إِنَّمَا الإِمَامُ لِيُؤْتَمَّ بِهِ فَلاَ تَخْتَلِفُوا عَلَيْهِ فَإِذَا كَبَّرَ فَكَبِّرُوا وَإِذَا رَكَعَ فَارْكَعُوا وَإِذَا قَالَ سَمِعَ اللَّهُ لِمَنْ حَمِدَهُ ‏.‏ فَقُولُوا اللَّهُمَّ رَبَّنَا لَكَ الْحَمْدُ ‏.‏ وَإِذَا سَجَدَ فَاسْجُدُوا وَإِذَا صَلَّى جَالِسًا فَصَلُّوا جُلُوسًا أَجْمَعُونَ ‏"‏ ‏.‏
   >
   > Abu Huraira reported: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) said: The Imam is appointed, so that he should be followed, so don't be at variance with him. Recite takbir when he recites it; bow down when he bows down and when he says:" Allah listens to him who praises Him," say:" O Allah, our Lord, to Thee be the Praise." And when he (the Imam) prostrates, you should also prostrate, and when he says prayer sitting, you should all observe prayer sitting.
   >
   > <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 4, Hadith 92](https://sunnah.com/muslim/4/92)</sub>
3. *Allahumma rabanna wa lakalḥamd ḥamdan kathīran ṭayyiban mubārakan fīh* (Arabic: اللهم ربنا ولك الحمد حمدا كثيرا طيبا مباركا فيه)

   > حَدَّثَنَا الْقَعْنَبِيُّ، عَنْ مَالِكٍ، عَنْ نُعَيْمِ بْنِ عَبْدِ اللَّهِ الْمُجْمِرِ، عَنْ عَلِيِّ بْنِ يَحْيَى الزُّرَقِيِّ، عَنْ أَبِيهِ، عَنْ رِفَاعَةَ بْنِ رَافِعٍ الزُّرَقِيِّ، قَالَ كُنَّا يَوْمًا نُصَلِّي وَرَاءَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم فَلَمَّا رَفَعَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم رَأْسَهُ مِنَ الرُّكُوعِ قَالَ ‏"‏ سَمِعَ اللَّهُ لِمَنْ حَمِدَهُ ‏"‏.‏ قَالَ رَجُلٌ وَرَاءَ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم اللَّهُمَّ رَبَّنَا وَلَكَ الْحَمْدُ حَمْدًا كَثِيرًا طَيِّبًا مُبَارَكًا فِيهِ فَلَمَّا انْصَرَفَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم قَالَ ‏"‏ مَنِ الْمُتَكَلِّمُ بِهَا آنِفًا ‏"‏.‏ فَقَالَ الرَّجُلُ أَنَا يَا رَسُولَ اللَّهِ.‏ فَقَالَ رَسُولُ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم ‏"‏ لَقَدْ رَأَيْتُ بِضْعَةً وَثَلاَثِينَ مَلَكًا يَبْتَدِرُونَهَا أَيُّهُمْ يَكْتُبُهَا أَوَّلَ ‏"‏.‏
   >
   > Rifa'ah ibn Rafi' said: One day we were praying behind the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ). When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) raised his head after bowing, he said: Allah listened to him who praised Him. A man behind the Messenger of Allah(ﷺ) said: O Allah, Our Lord, and to Thee be praise, much praise, good and blessed. When the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) finished his prayer, he asked: Which of you if the one who spoke (the words) just now. The man said: I (uttered) these words, Prophet of Allah. The Messenger of Allah(ﷺ) said: I saw more than thirty angels racing against one another to be the one to write them first.
   >
   > <sub>— [Sunan Abi Dawud, Book 2, Hadith 380](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/2/380)</sub>
4. *Rabanna wa lakalḥamd mil' as-samāwāti wa al-arḍ wa mil' ma shi'ta min shay'in ba'd* (Arabic: ربنا ولك الحمد ملء السموات وملء الأرض وملء ما بينهما وملء ما شئت من شيء بعد)

   > حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ أَبِي بَكْرٍ الْمُقَدَّمِيُّ، حَدَّثَنَا يُوسُفُ الْمَاجِشُونُ، حَدَّثَنِي أَبِي، عَنْ عَبْدِ، الرَّحْمَنِ الأَعْرَجِ عَنْ عُبَيْدِ اللَّهِ بْنِ أَبِي رَافِعٍ، عَنْ عَلِيِّ بْنِ أَبِي طَالِبٍ، عَنْ رَسُولِ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم أَنَّهُ كَانَ إِذَا قَامَ إِلَى الصَّلاَةِ قَالَ ‏"‏ وَجَّهْتُ وَجْهِيَ لِلَّذِي فَطَرَ السَّمَوَاتِ وَالأَرْضَ حَنِيفًا وَمَا أَنَا مِنَ الْمُشْرِكِينَ إِنَّ صَلاَتِي وَنُسُكِي وَمَحْيَاىَ وَمَمَاتِي لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ لاَ شَرِيكَ لَهُ وَبِذَلِكَ أُمِرْتُ وَأَنَا مِنَ الْمُسْلِمِينَ اللَّهُمَّ أَنْتَ الْمَلِكُ لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ أَنْتَ.‏ أَنْتَ رَبِّي وَأَنَا عَبْدُكَ ظَلَمْتُ نَفْسِي وَاعْتَرَفْتُ بِذَنْبِي فَاغْفِرْ لِي ذُنُوبِي جَمِيعًا إِنَّهُ لاَ يَغْفِرُ الذُّنُوبَ إِلاَّ أَنْتَ وَاهْدِنِي لأَحْسَنِ الأَخْلاَقِ لاَ يَهْدِي لأَحْسَنِهَا إِلاَّ أَنْتَ وَاصْرِفْ عَنِّي سَيِّئَهَا لاَ يَصْرِفُ عَنِّي سَيِّئَهَا إِلاَّ أَنْتَ لَبَّيْكَ وَسَعْدَيْكَ وَالْخَيْرُ كُلُّهُ فِي يَدَيْكَ وَالشَّرُّ لَيْسَ إِلَيْكَ أَنَا بِكَ وَإِلَيْكَ تَبَارَكْتَ وَتَعَالَيْتَ أَسْتَغْفِرُكَ وَأَتُوبُ إِلَيْكَ ‏"‏.‏ وَإِذَا رَكَعَ قَالَ ‏"‏ اللَّهُمَّ لَكَ رَكَعْتُ وَبِكَ آمَنْتُ وَلَكَ أَسْلَمْتُ خَشَعَ لَكَ سَمْعِي وَبَصَرِي وَمُخِّي وَعَظْمِي وَعَصَبِي ‏"‏.‏ وَإِذَا رَفَعَ قَالَ ‏"‏ اللَّهُمَّ رَبَّنَا لَكَ الْحَمْدُ مِلْءَ السَّمَوَاتِ وَمِلْءَ الأَرْضِ وَمِلْءَ مَا بَيْنَهُمَا وَمِلْءَ مَا شِئْتَ مِنْ شَىْءٍ بَعْدُ ‏"‏.‏ وَإِذَا سَجَدَ قَالَ ‏"‏ اللَّهُمَّ لَكَ سَجَدْتُ وَبِكَ آمَنْتُ وَلَكَ أَسْلَمْتُ سَجَدَ وَجْهِي لِلَّذِي خَلَقَهُ وَصَوَّرَهُ وَشَقَّ سَمْعَهُ وَبَصَرَهُ تَبَارَكَ اللَّهُ أَحْسَنُ الْخَالِقِينَ ‏"‏.‏ ثُمَّ يَكُونُ مِنْ آخِرِ مَا يَقُولُ بَيْنَ التَّشَهُّدِ وَالتَّسْلِيمِ ‏"‏ اللَّهُمَّ اغْفِرْ لِي مَا قَدَّمْتُ وَمَا أَخَّرْتُ وَمَا أَسْرَرْتُ وَمَا أَعْلَنْتُ وَمَا أَسْرَفْتُ وَمَا أَنْتَ أَعْلَمُ بِهِ مِنِّي أَنْتَ الْمُقَدِّمُ وَأَنْتَ الْمُؤَخِّرُ لاَ إِلَهَ إِلاَّ أَنْتَ ‏"‏.‏
   >
   > 'Ali ibn Abu Talib reported that when the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) got up at night for prayer he would say:
   >
   > I turn my face in complete devotion to One Who is the Originator of the heaven and the earth and I am not of the polytheists. Verily my prayer, my sacrifice, my living and my dying are for Allah, the Lord of the worlds; There is no partner with Him and this is what I have been commanded (to profess and believe) and I am of the believers. O Allah, Thou art the King, there is no god but Thee, Thou art my Lord, and I am Thy bondman. I wronged myself and make a confession of my Sin. Forgive all my sins, for no one forgives the sins but Thee, and guide me in the best of conduct for none but Thee guideth anyone (in) good conduct. Remove sins from me, for none else but Thou can remove sins from me. Here I am at Thy service, and Grace is to Thee and the whole of good is in Thine hand, and one cannot get nearneststo Thee through evil. My (power as well as existence) is due to Thee (Thine grace) and I turn to Thee (for supplication). Thou art blessed and Thou art exalted. I seek forgiveness from Thee and turn to Thee in repentance: and when he would bow, he would say: O Allah, it is for Thee that I bowed. I affirm my faith in Thee and I submit to Thee, and submit humbly before Thee my hearing, my eyesight, my marrow, my bone, my sinew; and when he would raise his head, he would say: O Allah, our Lord, praise is due to Thee, (the praise) with which is filled the heavens and the earth, and with which is filled that (space) which exists between them, and filled with anything that Thou desireth afterward. And when he prostrated himself, he (the Holy Prophet) would say: O Allah, it is to Thee that I prostrate myself and it is in Thee that I affirm my faith, and I submit to Thee. My face is submitted before One Who created it, and shaped it, and opened his faculties of hearing and seeing. Blessed is Allah, the best of Creators; and he would then say between Tashahhud and the pronouncing of salutation: Forgive me of the earlier and later open and secret (sins) and that where I made transgression and that Thou knowest better than I. Thou art the First and the Last. There is no god, but Thee.
   >
   > <sub>— [Sahih Muslim, Book 6, Hadith 240](https://sunnah.com/muslim/6/240)</sub>

Comment: Jazakallah Khair for the references.